# Using strftime in SQLite

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, strftime

My date stored in DB like this:

[image: date in long]

I need only month higher than 9

[image: date strftime]

But query still work with the old (before "strftime" command) long numbers.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: what datatype is `month`? because if is string you cant compare `'09' > 9`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strftime` always returns a string, and strings are considered larger than any number.

To get the correct result, use a string comparison:

```
... WHERE strftime(...) > '09'
```